# How can I change the hash sign in the url of a page to some other value?

Tags: javascript, url

WIth this code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
               window.location.hash="Aboutus"; 
  </script>
```

,I get url#Aboutus..
I want to change this sign to some other value ..How can I procees?

Comment: Can't `#` has semantic meaning.

Comment: I am using Ajax to load my pages ..When my ajax pages load i need to change the url witout reloading the page. that's it.

Comment: Changing the url fragment (part after `#`) doesn't cause a page reload

Comment: @Vimal: You can use: `window.onhashchange = function() { alert('hash hanged!' + location.hash);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the hash has special meaning in a url, it has to be a hash, not any other symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.href += "#Abouts";
alert(location.hash.slice(1)); //Abouts
```

Answer (score 0):

To change url without reload - you have to change hash. You a right. But hash is everything after `#` sign. So you can't change it.